# Jest saying sort is not a function even though test array is being set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I am trying to test a Vue component in Jest. The component has this in data:

```
data() {
  return {
    notes: [],
    selectedNote: null,
  }
}
```

and it has the following computed property to sort notes in reverse order:

```
orderedNotes() {
  console.log({orderedNotes: this.notes});
  return this.notes.sort( (a,b) => {
    return b.nb_entry_ordering - a.nb_entry_ordering;
  }
}
```

In my Jest test I am trying to test a method in the component that will update `notes` and therefore update `orderedNotes()`. However I keep getting an error that

```
this.notes.sort is not a function
```

I assumed it was because `this.notes` was not yet being set in my jest test, so I added the following setters to my Jest test:

```
 it('should not deselect note when denying delete function',() => {
        // sets global window.confirm() alert response to true, for testing the delete() method
        global.confirm = () => false;
        notebook.notes = testNotes;
        notebook.selectedNote = testNotes[1];

        notebook.deleteNote(1);
        expect(notebook.selectedNote).toBeTruthy();
    })
```

The test passes however I am still getting the error about `this.notes.sort` not being a function. Does anyone see why? here's the error log including a console log that I put into the `orderedNotes` computed property to check `this.notes`

```
console.log
      { orderedNotes: [] }

      at VueComponent.orderedNotes (resources/js/components/mods/notebook/Notebook.vue:61:1)

    console.log
      {
        orderedNotes: [
          {
            notebook_entry_id: [Getter/Setter],
            member_id: [Getter/Setter],
            content_id: [Getter/Setter],
            course_id: [Getter/Setter],
            domain_id: [Getter/Setter],
            response_id: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_ordering: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_created_ts: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_last_modified: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_subject: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_text: [Getter/Setter]
          },
          {
            notebook_entry_id: [Getter/Setter],
            member_id: [Getter/Setter],
            content_id: [Getter/Setter],
            course_id: [Getter/Setter],
            domain_id: [Getter/Setter],
            response_id: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_ordering: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_created_ts: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_last_modified: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_subject: [Getter/Setter],
            nb_entry_text: [Getter/Setter]
          }
        ]
      }

      at VueComponent.orderedNotes (resources/js/components/mods/notebook/Notebook.vue:61:1)

    console.log
      {
        orderedNotes: [Function: mockConstructor] {
          _isMockFunction: true,
          getMockImplementation: [Function],
          mock: [Getter/Setter],
          mockClear: [Function],
          mockReset: [Function],
          mockRestore: [Function],
          mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
          mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
          mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
          mockReturnValue: [Function],
          mockResolvedValue: [Function],
          mockRejectedValue: [Function],
          mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
          mockImplementation: [Function],
          mockReturnThis: [Function],
          mockName: [Function],
          getMockName: [Function]
        }
      }

      at VueComponent.orderedNotes (resources/js/components/mods/notebook/Notebook.vue:61:1)

    console.error
      [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.notes.sort is not a function"
      
      found in
      
      ---> <Notebook>
             <Root>

      at warn (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621:15)
      at logError (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1880:5)
      at globalHandleError (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1875:3)
      at handleError (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1835:5)
      at VueComponent.Vue._render (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3540:7)
      at VueComponent.updateComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4054:21)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4465:25)
      at Watcher.run (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4540:22)

    console.error
      TypeError: this.notes.sort is not a function
          at VueComponent.orderedNotes
```

and here are the test notes that I am setting:

```
export const testNotes = [
    { "notebook_entry_id": 1,
        "member_id": "17",
        "content_id": "0",
        "course_id": "528",
        "domain_id": "3",
        "response_id": null,
        "nb_entry_ordering": "1",
        "nb_entry_created_ts": "2021-02-17 10:56:25",
        "nb_entry_last_modified": "2021-02-18 14:39:10",
        "nb_entry_subject": "Subject One",
        "nb_entry_text": "<p>test test content</p>\n"
    },
    {
        "notebook_entry_id": 2,
        "member_id": "17",
        "content_id": "0",
        "course_id": "528",
        "domain_id": "3",
        "response_id": null,
        "nb_entry_ordering": "2",
        "nb_entry_created_ts": "2021-02-17 13:25:54",
        "nb_entry_last_modified": "2021-02-18 14:38:35",
        "nb_entry_subject": "Subject Two",
        "nb_entry_text": "<p>Test content</p>\n"
    }];
```

Could it be because I have a promise being mocked in the method I am testing?? In Jest before my test I have:

```
 //mock repo calls (axios calls are in the repo)
    NotebookRepo.delete = jest.fn(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(jest.fn());
    });

  //this one is called in this.getAllNotes()
    NotebookRepo.getAll = jest.fn(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(jest.fn());
    });
```

then in the component, this is the method that is being tested:

```
deleteNote(noteId) {
      let confirmed = confirm('Delete this note permanently?');

      if( confirmed ) {

        this.selectedNote = null;

        NotebookRepo.delete(
            this.userData.domain.id,
            this.userData.course.id,
            this.userData.member.id,
            noteId,
        );

        //refresh note list
        this.getAllNotes();

        return true;

      }

      return false;

    },
```

and here's getAllNotes which is referenced in Delete()

```
async getAllNotes( currentNote = null ) {

      this.notes = await NotebookRepo.getAll(
          this.userData.domain.id,
          this.userData.course.id,
          this.userData.member.id
      );

      if( currentNote ) {
        this.setCurrentNote(currentNote);
      }

    },
```

Comment: In the last console log of `this.notes` it is no longer an array, but a mock function. It's at this point `sort` will no longer exist (it is a prototype of an array). This will be causing your error, but there is not enough info in the post to see when you are mocking `this.notes`

Comment: I just updated with the things that are being tested in the component and the mock of the call to axios which returns a promise @oli

Comment: should I be returning the test notes array instead of a promise? I was getting an error when I wasn't returning a promise

Comment: I changed the mock from returning a promise to returning testNotes array and that fixed it!! Thank you if you make an answer I'll accept it